# what is the logic of the term 'object' in certain situations

Tags: java

I am a little bit confused with object's logic.

For example:

```
    class A
    {
     // do some stuff

    }

    class B
    {

    public A test()
     {
        // do some stuff
     }

    }
```

or consider this:

```
 class A
    {
      //do some stuff
    }

    class B
    {
      A someVariable;

      //do some stuff


    }
```

What does it mean "**A test()**"? I know it's a type of method, but where's the **logic**? How can I understand it. I read a lot of theory, but now i am confused with this logic and where can I use it. Help please.

Comment: In the future: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: What are you talking about? What logic? Are you asking where the implementation of the method is?

Answer (score 4):

`A test()` declares a method on the type `B` that takes no parameters and returns an instance of `A`.

Comment: I know it, but i need to get a logic of it. Sorry for a beginner question.

Comment: What do you mean by "a logic".  Like what it compiles to?